# Calculating means for multiple columns, in different rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file like this:

```
-Species-    -Strain-       -A-       -B-       -C-       -D-
 Species1    Strain1.1         0.2       0.1       0.1       0.4
 Species1    Strain1.1         0.2       0.7       0.2       0.2
 Species1    Strain1.2         0.1       0.6       0.1       0.3
 Species1    Strain1.1         0.2       0.6       0.2       0.6
 Species2    Strain2.1         0.3       0.3       0.3       0.1
 Species2    Strain2.2         0.6       0.2       0.6       0.2
 Species2    Strain2.2         0.2       0.1       0.4       0.2
```

And I would like to calculate a mean (average) for each unique strain for each of the columns (A-D) how would I go about doing it?

I tried `df.groupby(['Strain','Species']).mean().mean(1)` but that still seems to give me multiple versions of strains in the resulting dataframe, rather than the means for each columns for each unique strain.

Essentially I would like a mean result for A,B,C & D per strain.

Apologies for being unclear, I'm struggling to get my head around this, and I'm very new to programming!

Comment: it's still not very clear - do you care about the grouping of the strain to species? If not then you can do `df.groupby(['Strain']).mean()` this will give you the mean of `A,B,C,D` per strain.

Comment: if that's not the case can you edit your question to include the expected results please.

Comment: Yes this works when both 'Strain' and 'Species' are used, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you simply need to call

```
df.groupby(['Species', 'Strain']).mean()

                      A         B         C    D 
Species   Strain                               
Species1  Strain1.1  0.2  0.466667  0.166667  0.4
          Strain1.2  0.1  0.600000  0.100000  0.3
Species2  Strain2.1  0.3  0.300000  0.300000  0.1
          Strain2.2  0.4  0.150000  0.500000  0.2
```

What you were doing when you called `df.groupby(['Strain','Species']).mean().mean(1)` was taking the mean of the 4 means in `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`. `mean(1)` means take the mean over the first axis (*i.e.* over the columns).

Comment: Thanks, although when I do this I still get multiple results for the same strain, so I'll get, for example, strain 1.1 repeating multiple times when I only want the average for all the copies of strain 1.1

Comment: Nevermind! I wasn't saving to a new dataframe,

Using 
df2 = df.groupby(['Species', 'Strain']).mean()

Worked a treat, thanks!